# PostgreSQL: COUNT(*) uses a sequential scan, not index

Tags: postgresql, index, count

Why does PostgreSQL sequentially scans the table for `COUNT(*)` query, while there is a very small and indexed primary key?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [official wiki pages](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting) give an answer to that:

> [...] The reason why this is slow is related
>   to the MVCC implementation in
>   PostgreSQL. The fact that multiple
>   transactions can see different states
>   of the data means that there can be no
>   straightforward way for "COUNT(*)" to
>   summarize data across the whole table;
>   PostgreSQL must walk through all rows,
>   in some sense. This normally results
>   in a sequential scan reading
>   information about every row in the
>   table. [...]

Furthermore, you could try an [ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-analyze.html) to rebuild the info for the query planer.

You should get a better performance using `COUNT(an uniquly indexed field)` but if this is very big, a seq scan is the only way to do it.

If you need very quick numbers and are not afraid of querying the schema, you can do the following

```
SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 'your_table'::regclass
```

But don't rely on this values as it is only an "estimated" (although often the exact) number of tuples in the table.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  I haven't read anything anywhere, where `COUNT(pk)` will improve performance.  I think it will always do a seq-scan

Comment: Without a where clause you are correct, a seq scan will be performed.  With a sufficiently select where clause postgresql CAN use an index, but keep in mind it WILL go back to the table to verify the visibility of the tuples it's reporting on.

Comment: Another way to get the estimated row count that I find easier to remember is `EXPLAIN SELECT * from your_table;`. This won't execute the query. The output includes `rows=…` with the estimated number of rows.

Comment: FYI - count should be faster since postgres 9.2 - https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/10/12/count-performance/#distinct_counts_exact_index